# XNA: int as Vector2 so i can move sprite

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I am really new XNA programming, and i am having a big problem. I have a Vector2, spritePosistion, that controls what position the sprite is at, now i want to move it by 1, every time that a player hits the w button, it is having a problem 1 being and int and spritePosistion being a Vector2. So am i doing it wrong or is there a way of getting these things to work together. 
Here is the code

```
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
{
    // This is the problem 
    spritePosition += 1;
}
```

Comment: You need to [study vectors](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/vector/info).

Answer (score 3):

It depends, you're being awfully vague in your question. For instance, in which direction do you want to move? A few examples...

- Right `spritePosition.X += 1`
- Left `spritePosition.X -= 1`
- Down `spritePosition.Y += 1`
- Up `spritePosition.Y -= 1`

Answer (score 2):

You said you want to "move the sprite by one" - but in which direction? Try

```
spritePosition.X += 1;
```

or

```
spritePosition.Y += 1;
```

for X or Y movement.